# Output after groupby and aggregation

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a PANDAS dataframe. When I make a GROUP BY and an aggregation function such as min or max, I get only partial results, namely the column on which I made the min/max aggregation on a numeric column. How can I get the full line, ie all the data corresponding to this min/max?

The dataframe looks llike:

```
Place    Year   Time        TimeS
BOSTON   1973   02:16:03    8163
FUKUOKA  1973   02:11:45    7905
NEW YORK 1973   02:21:54    8514
BERLIN   1974   02:44:53    9893
BOSTON   1974   02:13:39    8019
FUKUOKA  1974   02:11:32    7892
NEW YORK 1974   02:26:30    8790
```

I want the min or max time realized per year and the city. I can only get the time with (marathon is the name of the pandas.DataFrame)

```
marathon.groupby('year').TimeS.max()
```

that gives:

```
1973    02:21:54
1974    02:44:53
```

How can I have the place that corresponds to this time?
Namely:

```
NEW YORK   1973    02:21:54
BERLIN     1974    02:44:53
```

Comment: Are `Year` and `Time` index columns? Or are none of these the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, definitely. Here's two:

```py
marathon[marathon.TimeS == marathon.groupby('Year').TimeS.transform('max')]
```

or

```py
marathon[marathon.TimeS.isin(marathon.groupby('Year').TimeS.max())]
```

Let's check out some of these intermediate objects

```
In [29]: marathon.groupby('Year').TimeS.max()
Out[29]:
Year
1973    8514
1974    9893
Name: TimeS, dtype: int64
```

So we get a series, but only of two values. So we can index the dataframe wherever the column values are equal to one of these, which is the second solution.

The first solution uses `transform('max')` instead, which preserves the size of the dataframe:

```
In [30]: marathon.groupby('Year').TimeS.transform('max')
Out[30]:
0    8514
1    8514
2    8514
3    9893
4    9893
5    9893
6    9893
Name: TimeS, dtype: int64
```

So now it's the same size and we can just compare equality directly to the columns that it's equal to.

Note that if the max values occur multiple times, both of these methods will return the duplicates as well---that may or may not be what you want.